# How to show that $\sqrt[3]{p} \neq a+b\sqrt{q}$ for any $a,b\in \mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

p and q are primes, they could be same or different numbers. a and b are in $\mathbb{Q}$. I'm trying to prove that $\sqrt[3]{p} \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{q})$, and I think this is how to do it.

After that, how do I show that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{q}, \sqrt[3]{p}):\mathbb{Q}]=6$?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose to the contrary, therefore
$$
(a+b\sqrt q)^3=a^3+3ab^2q+\sqrt q(3a^2b+b^3q)\in\mathbb Q
$$
Hence $(3a^2b+b^3q)=0$, but $b\neq0$, hence
$$
0<(3a^2+b^2q)=0
$$
Which contradicts.

Answer (score 1):

It would imply $\mathbf Q(\sqrt[3]p)\subset\mathbf Q(\sqrt q)$. Hoever
$$\bigl[\mathbf Q(\sqrt[3]p):\mathbf Q\bigr]=3,\enspace\text{while}\enspace\bigl[\mathbf Q(\sqrt q):\mathbf Q\bigr]=2. $$